# Make authenticated request from React to Express api deployed in Firebse function

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, jwt

I had very simple Firebase authentication in a React app

```
export const register = async (
  email: string,
  password: string,

) => {
  try {
    return await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) alert(error.message);
  }
};

export const login = async (email: string, password: string) => {
  try {
    return await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) alert(error.message);
  }
};
```

I developed all my other APIs locally on Node. The issue was I needed role based access so I had to change my authentication. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/firebase/role-based-firebase-authentication) and ended up with a very similar users api in my express project. I deployed my whole express app as a function in Firebase.

I want to have my users and login in Firebase but check the custom claims on their token to:

1. control access to my api (back end level)
2. Have protected routes & adapt UI based on access level (front end level)

Where I'm stuck: making an authenticated request to the users service from React

I am adding the token to my request with an Axios interceptor

```
export const authenticatedRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiEndpoint,
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/JSON",
  },
});

authenticatedRequest.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  const token = getTokenFromLocalStorage();
  if (token) {
    config.headers!.authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
  return config;
});
```

I had a React context with the user before but I cannot access that outside my component tree to use in my interceptor, so I tried to either store the user or the token in local storage.

```
 onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
    setUser(currentUser);

    if (currentUser) {
      localStorage.setItem("capstone-user", JSON.stringify(currentUser));
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem("capstone-user");
    }

    if (currentUser && "accessToken" in currentUser) {
      localStorage.setItem(
        "capstone-accessToken",
        JSON.stringify(currentUser.accessToken)
      );
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem("capstone-accessToken");
    }
  });
```

Trying to get the token from the user leads to this error 'TypeError: user.getIdToken is not a function'

```
 const user = getUserFromLocalStorage();
  const token = user?.getIdToken();
```

Logging the currentUser to the console I noticed there is an accessToken on the user so tried to store that and make the request but I get a 401. I am verifying the token like this on my backend

```
 const decodedToken: admin.auth.DecodedIdToken = await admin
      .auth()
      .verifyIdToken(token);
    console.log("decodedToken", JSON.stringify(decodedToken));
    res.locals = {
      ...res.locals,
      uid: decodedToken.uid,
      role: decodedToken.role,
      email: decodedToken.email,
    };
    return next();
```

and getting this error: **app/invalid-credential -  Failed to determine project ID: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND**

Comment: Try with `const token = await auth.currentUser?.getIdToken();` and Have you initialized the admin sdk correctly as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add-sdk)

Comment: If you mean the  `const app = initializeApp();`  step, yes, but I do not have additional FIREBASE_CONFIG (how would that look?). The function deployed successfully (meaning I could hit the public api)

Comment: You should always initialize the admin sdk with `import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();` (this is in typescript) and try deploying it again

Comment: Hi does that solve your issue ?

Comment: That is how I initialized it. I think my issue might be trying to hit the api on my local server, I'll try to hit the deployment of the cloud function a few hours later when I'm home. I'll give an update if I face the same issue there, but how do I properly initialize firebase-admin to work for npm run dev ?

Comment: You can test this with firebase emulator but then you need to replicate a lot of stuff : (

Comment: Answer for the "TypeError: user.getIdToken is not a function'" is below. Please limit yourself to a single problem/question per post.

Comment: It worked while hitting the deployed cloud function. ` Failed to determine project ID` makes sense to me since I tried to hit it locally. The question would be more: how to implement something that meets my requirements (login through Firebase, but check token claims on my APIs), but thanks for the answer Frank! Unfortunately I still had an error. What worked for me is saving the token in local storage inside onAuthStateChanged and avoiding getIdToken. If that's not a bad pattern I'll stick with it

Comment: The ID token expires an hour after it was minted, and its lifecycle is not part of `onAuthStateChanged`. If you want to use a listener based approach (great idea), use `onIdTokenChaged` for that part: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#onidtokenchanged

Answer (score 0):

For this error:

> TypeError: user.getIdToken is not a function

The problem is that you're using SDK version 9 or later, which uses a new modular syntax where `getIdToken()` (like many other APIs) is declared as a [top-level function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#getidtoken).

So the proper syntax is:

```
const token = getIdToken(user!);
```

Don't forget to add `getIdToken` to your imports.

Comment: Having "firebase-auth": "^0.1.2" as dependency, I try to import it with `import { getIdToken } from "firebase/auth"; ` and I still get " _firebase_util__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.getModularInstance(...).getIdToken is not a function"